# Why is the function onCreate() in JobService() always launched in Android?

Tags: android

In my mind, the `JobService()` is subclass of service class, it will be resident in system for a long time.

`onCreate()` will be invoked only one time and `onStartJob` will be invoked periodically.

So I think that the result will be

```
Start Server
OnCreate
Starting
Starting
Starting
```

But in fact,  onCreate() is always launched before onStartJob(), you can see the Image ,why?

It seems that the system release `RestoreService : JobService()` quickly, but why doesn't onStopJob() to be invoked when the system release  `RestoreService : JobService()`?

**Image**

[image]

**Code**

```
private fun startScheduleRestore(mContext:Context){
   logError("Start Server")

   val interval=10 *1000L

    val mJobScheduler = mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

    val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(mContext.getInteger(R.integer.JobID), ComponentName(mContext, RestoreService::class.java))
                        .setPeriodic(interval)
                        .setPersisted(true)
                        .build()

    mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
}



class RestoreService : JobService() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        logError("OnCreate")
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        logError("OnDestory")
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        Thread(Runnable { completeRestore(params) }).start()
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        logError("OnStop")
        return false
    }


    fun completeRestore(parameters: JobParameters) {
        logError("Starting")
        jobFinished(parameters, false)
    }

}
```

Comment: Services are not necessarily resident for a long time. In fact, Google has been pushing developers away from using services in that manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in fact, onCreate() is always launched before onStartJob(), you
>   can see the Image, why?

This is because according to your business logic the RestoreService is starting, doing the important things you provided in `onStartJob()` method and once done will destroy when you call  `jobFinished()` method.

> It seems that the system release RestoreService : JobService()
>   quickly, but why doesn't onStopJob() to be invoked when the system
>   release  RestoreService : JobService()?

`onStopJob()` method is called if the system has determined that you must stop the execution of your job even before you've had a chance to call jobFinished(JobParameters, boolean).

Comment: Thanks, does it mean that JobService() isn't  normal server? it can release itselft by calling jobFinished(parameters, false)

Comment: So jobService() is always rebuild every time if I invoke jobFinished(parameters, false) when I execute  mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo), right?

Comment: Thanks, does it mean that JobService() isn't normal server? it can release itselft by calling jobFinished(parameters, false)
>> True.

Comment: So jobService() is always rebuild every time if I invoke jobFinished(parameters, false) when I execute mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo), right?
>> Yes, by calling jobFinished() parameter you are explicitly telling your service to destroy and service will call onCreate again in next interval.

Answer (score 1):

This is inline with the lifecycle of service defined by Google. `onCreate` will be called only once throughout the life-cycle of JobService.

> Called by the system when the service is first created.

Since you are calling `jobFinished` in `completeRestore` your `RestoreService`will be destroyed and your next schedule will result in creating new RestoreService. This in turn will call `onCreate`

Comment: Thanks! This is my question, why is onCreate fired every time ?

Comment: You know  RestoreService is server, it will be resident in system for a long time